# JQuery can not update the contents

Tags: jquery

Our Wordpress page is updated with a JQuery script. Recently, without change, the update no longer works and nothing can be added to the page. This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var paper_list_comp = list_with_stag('publication', 
    function(){
    <?php if(current_user_can('administrator')) { ?>
        jQuery('#paper-list-control').html('<button id="paper-list-admin-add">Publications</button>');
        jQuery('#paper-list-admin-add').button().click(function() { on_publication_click(-1); });
    <?php } // end if ?>
        jQuery('#paper-list').html('');
    },
    function(idx, token){
        var str = token.replace(/^\[(.*)\]$/, '$1');
        if(str.length<=0) return;
        var p = JSON.parse(str);
        var content = "<div class="paper-detail" onclick="on_publication_click("+idx+");"><span class="paper-author">"+p.author+"</span><span class="paper-title">"+p.title+"</span><span class="paper-publication">"+p.publication+"</span><span class="paper-link"><a href=""+p.href+"">"+p.link+"</a></span>";
        if(p.supp_link!=undefined && p.supp_href!=undefined) {
        content += "<span class="paper-supp-link"><a href=""+p.supp_href+"">"+p.supp_link+"</a></span>";
        }
        content += "</div>";
        jQuery("#paper-list").prepend(content);
        return p;
    }
);
paper_list_comp.refresh();

var on_publication_click = function(idx) {
    window.open(paper_list_comp.data[idx].href);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "page cannot be updated anymore, no changes can be added".

Comment: Are you sure this is not a backend problem? Have you tried making the same requests using curl?

Comment: Hi, gsk, what I mean is that as designed, by clicking the modify button there will be a pop window where I can add information for a new record, and after submit it. It will show on the page. However nothing changes now even after I submit the new record

Comment: Hi, George, I am not sure whether it is a backend problem or not. We have been using it for 2 years without problem. This weird thing happened since 3 weeks ago

Comment: Are you seeing javascript errors in the developer console (part of your browser)? Is your database updating at all? 'Not working' is insufficient data to diagnose what is going on: some sort of error message or even a success message goes a long way.